# How to parse this date format "Wednesday, 12 June 2019 14:23:39" to this "2019-03-05T11:56:13Z" in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, format, simpledateformat

How do I parse this date "Wednesday, 12 June 2019 14:23:39" which comes as a String to a date format like this "2019-03-05T11:56:13Z" in JAVA?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I know we’re picky here: one of the things we expect from questioner’s is you search an research before posting your question. You’re likely to find many answers (good and bad ones) faster than anyone can type an answer here. [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: You tagged your question simpledateformat. You don’t want to use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is poorly designed and notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is the exact result? The trainling `z` in `2019-03-05T11:56:13Z` indicates UTC, but your source string doesn’t inform us of a time zone or offset. Which is it? Without knowing we cannot make the conversion correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `java.time` API for this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Wednesday, 12 June 2019 14:23:39", dateTimeFormatter);
String isoDateTime = localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(isoDateTime);
```

which results in:

```
2019-06-12T14:23:39
```

Answer (score 0):

attached example of how you can parsar your date

greetings

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {



    String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";

    // *** note that it's "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"  
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = dt.parse(date_s);

    // *** same for the format String below
    SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM  yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR0Lb.png)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.